# Error: This contract may be abstract

Tags: contract-development, remix, erc-20, constructor, abstract

My solidity contract compiles in Remix, but when I try to deploy it it fails and throws

```
Error: This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.
```

Here is the contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

/**
 * @title DetailedERC20 token
 * @dev The decimals are only for visualization purposes.
 * All the operations are done using the smallest and indivisible token unit,
 * just as on Ethereum all the operations are done in wei.
 */
abstract contract ExampleToken is ERC20Detailed {

  //We inherited the DetailedERC20 
  constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals) 
  ERC20Detailed(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
  public {
  }

}
```

For constructor parameters I used `Mooncoin`, `MNC`, `6`

Comment: I get an error message from remix when I delete "abstract."

Answer (score 3):

Contract `ERC20Detailed` inherits from [interface IERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol), which declares the following functions:

```
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
```

Hence any contract which inherits from contract `ERC20Detailed` needs to implement these functions in order to be deployable.

You might also need to get rid of the `abstract` prefix at the beginning of your contract declaration. I'm not familiar with this keyword myself (it was probably added to the language only recently), but I believe that it tells the compiler that the author's intention is to leave some functions unimplemented.